# Input string incorrect format

Tags: c#

I need help, I'm getting error: Input string had an incorrect format.
Thanks in advance.

```
FORM2.CS:

    public void loadClient(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        client = Client.GetClients()[0];
        short port = short.Parse(f1.returnTBOX4().Text);
        client.Login.SetOT(f1.returnTBOX3().Text, port);
    }


FORM1.CS:

    public TextBox returnTBOX1()
    {
        return textBox1;
    }

    public TextBox returnTBOX2()
    {
        return textBox2;
    }

    public TextBox returnTBOX3()
    {
        return textBox3;
    }

    public TextBox returnTBOX4()
    {
        return textBox4;
    }
```

Comment: You should replace those methods with properties that return the `Text` s.

Comment: Also, **NAME YOUR CONTROLS**!   There is (almost) nothing worse than forms with controls like `textBox1`, `button3`, `comboBox12`, `checkBox37`, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because of mismatch between what you type and what is interpreted (current culture settings are in use). If you want to always provide this number in an invariant form, use following code:

```
using System.Globalization;

short.Parse(f1.returnTBOX4().Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't tell us where the error was this might not be the right place:

change this:

```
short.Parse(f1.returnTBOX4().Text)
```

to this:

```
short my_val;

if(short.TryParse(f1.returnTBOX4().Text, out my_val)){

  Do stuff

}
else{
  log exception and display to use that information was in incorrect format.
}
```

This won't solve your problem with getting a bad value, but it will allow you to check the value and not have the parse method throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Form1 f1 = new Form1();
```

You are creating a *new* instance of the form.  That form is not going to have anything entered in the textBox4 control, the Parse() method will of course complain about it.  You have to use the *existing* instance of the form, the one that the user is looking at.  Pass a reference to it through the Form2 constructor.  Or use a property.  Or use Application.OpenForms if you really have to.